# Insert is not working php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Following is my code

```
$sqlcreate = "INSERT INTO PRTJOBSTATUS (INTJOBNO,SLNO,OPDATE,OPERTYPE,OPUSER,REMARKS,STATUSCODE,STATDATE)
            values (:int,:sn,:opdate,:optype,:opuser,:rmks,:stscode,:stdate)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlcreate);
    $stmt->bindValue(':int',$intjobno);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sn',$slno);
    $stmt->bindValue(':opdate',$today);
    $stmt->bindValue(':optype',$optype);
    $stmt->bindValue(':opuser',$opuser);
    $stmt->bindValue(':rmks',$remarks);
    $stmt->bindValue(':stscode',$statuscode);
    $stmt->bindValue(':stdate',$today);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Inserted";
```

While running its printing "Inserted", but not updating in my oracle database.

Comment: Are you doing *any* error checking? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: maybe do you need `commit` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - *There Sam. OP has enough to go on...* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: I put          if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
 }     after prepare statement. nothing printing...

Comment: How to commit using pdo??